# How to remove layers by name from .prototxt in caffe using Python

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have a `train.prototxt` create with Python code and would like to remove the `loss` layers to create the `deploy.prototxt` automatically. However, I know only the method to remove a layer by an integer like this:

```
net_param = deploy_net.to_proto()
del net_param.layer[0]
```

Is there any possibility to remove a layer by its name? Where is the documentation for the Python API? I cannot really find it. Do I just have to look at the C++ code and try to convert it into Python code?

**EDIT**

I am initialising the net with.

```
net = caffe.NetSpec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net.layer_dict` is a dictionary of all the layer. So to delete you can do:

`del net.layer_dict['layer_name'];`

You can look into `pycaffe.py` for details of Python Api.

Comment: I am receiving this error: `del net.layer_dict['loss']
  File "/../net_spec.py", line 176, in __getattr__
    return self.tops[name]
KeyError: 'layer_dict' ` Did you miss something in your answer?

Comment: I thought you loaded a prototxt. In case of custom use `del net.tops['loss'];` .

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: 'Net' object has no attribute 'layer_dict'`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393753/5437090) answer, you can also do the following to add `force_backward=true` and remove any layer from `deploy.prototxt` file without modifying a original file:

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format

model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open(model_path + 'deploy.prototxt').read(), model)
model.force_backward = True
model.layer.remove(model.layer[-1]) # remove the last layer 'prob' for example
open(model_path + 'tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))
net = caffe.Net(model_path + 'tmp.prototxt', model_path + 'model.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
```